Postgres: "secondary" primary key
How would one have dynamic "secondary" keys? For example, how we have it in Jira. We have a project name, for example "Test" with the shortcut "TEST". All associated tickets in this project are given a ID "TEST-1234", "TEST-1235", and so on.
How would one model this in Postgres?
In my mind, I worked out a table project with name VARCHAR(xx) and short VARCHAR(8). The ticket table would somehow look like this:
CREATE TABLE ticket 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    project_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    identifier INTEGER ???,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id),
)

How would you construct an identifier that is incrementing for every new ticket that is referencing the same project_id?


By it's definition there can only be one Primary Key for a table. 2) Why do you need this? You have ticket referencing project and you can build an on the fly identifier as project_id::text || '_' || id::text.  You could do this as generated column as shown here Create Table GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expr ) .


@AdrianKlaver, sorry it seems I did not describe my "problem" well enough. If I'd use your suggestion it would leave me with TEST-1 and for another project PROD, the first created ticket would be PROD-2, which is not the behaviour I want.

You're looking for individual sequences per group: here's a thread that's pretty much identical. Apologies to everyone who got a closed thread notification. I can't get used to it but whenever I suggest a duplicate, it immediately closes the thread instead of linking them and adding a comment suggesting a look and waiting for votes, like it used to. My bad.

@Zegarek, sorry for the inconvenience, I was not sure how to call the issue, and therefore did not find the older threads. But thanks for linking!

These are examples from the older thread I suggested, adjusted to your schema:
demo1 at db<>fiddle
create table ticket_id_per_project(
  project_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES project(id),
  max_ticket_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);

create function f_ticket_ids()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
    insert into ticket_id_per_project as f
    values (new.project_id,1)
    on conflict (project_id) do update
    set max_ticket_id=f.max_ticket_id+1
    returning format('PROJECT_%s_TICKET_%s',project_id,max_ticket_id)
    into new.identifier;
    
    return new;
end $f$;

create trigger t_ticket_ids before insert on ticket
for each row execute function f_ticket_ids();

It makes no attempt at removing gaps or correcting manually broken sequences - if you remove a ticket, you're left with a gap there. Also, all concurrent insert into ticket attempts for the same project, have to wait for predecessors to finish - the delay is negligible but non-zero. Example with brand-new projects and fresh tickets:
with gen_projects as (
  insert into project 
  select from generate_series(1,3) 
  returning *)
insert into ticket(project_id)
select id from gen_projects
returning *;




id
project_id
identifier




1
1
PROJECT_1_TICKET_1


2
2
PROJECT_2_TICKET_1


3
3
PROJECT_3_TICKET_1



The ticket counter continues for each existing project individually:
with pick_projects as (
  select id from project tablesample bernoulli(50)repeatable(.42)limit 2)
insert into ticket(project_id)
select id from pick_projects cross join lateral generate_series(1,3)
returning *;




id
project_id
identifier




4
2
PROJECT_2_TICKET_2


5
3
PROJECT_3_TICKET_2


6
2
PROJECT_2_TICKET_3


7
3
PROJECT_3_TICKET_3


8
2
PROJECT_2_TICKET_4


9
3
PROJECT_3_TICKET_4



You can trade that for only locking if they all insert the first ticket for a given project. Otherwise, concurrently inserted tickets for the same project don't block each other:
demo2 at db<>fiddle
create function seeded_sequence_nextval(seed text) returns int as $f$
declare sequence_name text:='seeded_sequence_'||seed;
begin 
  begin execute format('create sequence if not exists %I;',sequence_name);
  exception when /*23505*/unique_violation then null;--concurrent create if not exists
  end;
  return nextval(format('%I',sequence_name));
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function f_ticket_ids()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
    select format( 'PROJECT_%s_TICKET_%s'
                  ,new.project_id
                  ,seeded_sequence_nextval('tickets_project_'||new.project_id)) 
    into new.identifier;
    return new;
end $f$;

The function was swapped in-place, so there's no need to redefine the trigger. Works just the same, except for the locking.

Regarding the second example: there are voices against seeded sequences, or spawning many sequences in general (check out the exchange here). I'm yet to see reasonable benchmarks that would substantiate those concerns - you're more likely to need a thorough schema remodeling or even changing your stack, than to be concerned with the (yet to be determined number of) too many sequence objects.

I agree. Depending on the organization, the services accounts to use production databases may not allow DDL (such as CREATE SEQUENCE) but only SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT. Sometimes even DELETE is not allowed.

@TheImpaler That's a good point, although there's always the option to set up seeded_sequence_nextval() with security definer, not the default security invoker - that way only the definer needs the privilege to create those sequences and the svc account calling it won't have to be given any overreaching access.


How would you construct an identifier that is incrementing for every new ticket that is referencing the same project_id?

Per-project serials are subject to race conditions. The best solution depends on the complete situation.
One way: every session that wants to write a new a ticket row has to lock the parent row in table project first, to get (limited) exclusive write access for just the given project. This way you eliminate race conditions without blocking the whole ticket table.
Like:
BEGIN;
SELECT FROM parent
WHERE  parent_id = 123
FOR    NO KEY UPDATE;

INSERT INTO ticket
      (project_id, identifier)                       -- more columns?
SELECT 123       , COALESCE(max(identifier) + 1, 1)  -- more values?
FROM   ticket
WHERE  project_id = 123;
COMMIT;

The subquery always returns a row due to the aggregate function. So this even works for the first row per project, starting with 1.
A multicolumn index on (project_id, identifier) makes this very fast. You should typically have that in any case. Could be your PRIMARY KEY - or a "secondary" PK (a UNIQUE constraint) besides the (optional!) surrogate PK id.

A SELECT with MAX(value) + 1 is the most ugly trick to increase a counter value... This cause locking all the table (max) and thre is no guarantee thta a value will be assigned only for one user in race condition !

@SQLpro The lock is on project (here parent), and not on the whole table, but on the single project that's getting the ticket. The max() doesn't come with any sort of a lock although it either assumes there's an index on ticket.identifier that it can pop a max() from, or that scanning it for each insert is cheap. There's no race condition because in order to attempt that insert, the client has to first wait in line asking for a lock on the target project. The tally table the seeded sequences are faster and the latter hardly ever needs to lock but this right here wins in brevity.

NO... because PG by default use an optimistic locking. There is no solution in an explicit transaction even if the transastion isolation level is raise to SERIALIZABLE, until the transaction begin by an update or insert

@SQLpro This transaction opens by grabbing the lock explicitly on that one row in parent and it keeps it until commit - I'm not sure how the general optimistic locking design affects the explicitly acquired lock but I'm open if you have a link or a demo I could take a look at.

@SQLpro Here's a demo where I deploy some concurrent clients where you can observe in pg_locks how they politely queue up to get the tuple-level lock on the project and progressively get it and run an adequate insert, releasing it, only one holding it at a time: demo. This works just fine.

@SQLpro Both your comments are ... well, not true.

You could do this with a relative counter like so
1) create a counter table like this one :
CREATE TABLE t_counter 
   (table_name VARCHAR(63), 
    item_name VARCHAR(32), 
    id_value INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (table_name, item_name));

2) create a function to increase the counter and give a new value :
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_new_id 
   (tbl VARCHAR(63), 
    itm VARCHAR(32))
 RETURNS int
AS '
DECLARE n int;
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   t_counter 
                  WHERE  table_name = tbl
                         AND item_name = itm)
    THEN 
       INSERT INTO t_counter 
       VALUES (tbl, itm, 0);
       n := 1;
    ELSE
       UPDATE t_counter
       SET    id_value = id_value + 1
       WHERE  table_name = tbl
              AND  item_name = itm
       RETURNING id_value + 1 INTO n;
    END IF;
    RETURN n;
END ; '
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

3) use it in queries like :
SELECT get_new_id('ticket', 'TEST')


This not exists introduces a race condition. Two clients both trying to open a ticket for a project that doesn't yet have any tickets on it, will both see the same thing (no tickets present), and they will both try to insert the 0th ticket. You can swap the whole thing for a single, atomic upsert to fix that.

NO... because of the primary key that will be violate and raise an exception and the fact that FUNCTION are atomic when in INSERT or UPDATE queries...

I see the constraint. I'm not saying they'll both successfully insert the 0th ticket, only that they'll both attempt - one will fail, which OP will have to handle.

Here's a test showing what I have in mind: demo. Out of 8 concurrent clients deployed, only 1 succeeds and the rest fail with the PK violation error. It's the same setup as the test showing the idea with explicit lock on project works without race conditions.
